# Is onlyoffice support merge two word document?

Tags: merge, onlyoffice

I want merge two word document createed by onlyoffice, support or not ?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no implemented methods for merging documents, but it is possible to implement data transfer to JSON format
[Document.ToJSON()](https://api.onlyoffice.com/docbuilder/textdocumentapi/apidocument/tojson) from a document to a new document using the docbuilder script.

Accordingly, it is possible to open several documents in succession for data transfer this way:

```
// First document
builder.CreateFile("docx");
...
GlobalVariable["JSON"] = json;
builder.CloseFile();

// Second document
builder.CreateFile("docx");
    var json = GlobalVariable["JSON"]
builder.SaveFile("docx", "DocContentToJSON.docx");
builder.CloseFile();
```

Using document builder, you can also open your own documents.

Example of script for opening documents are available at [this link](https://api.onlyoffice.com/docbuilder/textdocumentapi#OpenDoc).